# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in inheriting class

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, iboutlet

I created a CustomTopTabbarController to customize the tab bar.

```
@objcMembers public class CustomTopTabbarController:UITabBarController {

@IBOutlet weak var customBar: UITabBar!
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    customBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:  0, width: customBar.frame.size.width, height: customBar.frame.size.height)

}

public override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}
}
```

In my main class, if I push CustomTopBarController then the tabBar loads as expected.

```
CustomTopTabbarController *controller = [CustomTopTabbarController controllerStoryboard:UTILITY];
```

I created another class which inherits CustomTopBarController

```
@objcMembers public class ReviewController:CustomTopTabbarController {
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()     
}

public override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}
}
```

However, if I push this controller from the same main class

```
ReviewController *controller = [ReviewController controllerStoryboard:COURSE];
```

the app crashes because customBar variable is nil. I receive an error:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I am not able to understand why customBar is initialized earlier and not now. Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: Please show what you did in Storyboard.

Comment: Is is hooked properly?

Comment: It is hooked properly. If it hadn't been then the wouldn't have worked upon pushing the CustomTopTabbarController as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have added a new scene to your storyboard file, changed the class of it's view controller to `ReviewController` and tried to load it from the storyboard.

If you do something like this you have to connect all your outlets to the `ReviewController` separately. Those connections are not inherited between the scenes. This is why inheritance of the view controllers is not very useful when it comes to the interface builder.